# :before :after HR Values for Site Title on Transparent Background

Tags: html, css

Running into a bit of a conundrum.

[image: Photoshop Mockup]

The following image is a site title area and has a background image (to the body of the HTML document). I am then throwing in transparent background to the entire container (which is basically a cross-browser translucent background -- dark brown). On top of that, I am using a PNG-24 slice for the darker edges. The part I'm stuck on is utilizing :before and :after (or if it's even possible) to create the "orange" lines on either side of the title. Normally, this would be as simple as applying the orange line as one solid image for example and then applying a background color to the `h1`, but in this case, we are working with transparent background images, which won't work. I've been bumping my head against the wall for a while with this one, but am at a loss if it's even possible - I haven't found an HTML entity for HR if that would work). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your header is one-line (and therefore disabling line-wrapping is acceptable), you can use table presentation:

```
<style>
H2 {display: table; width: 100%; }
H2 > SPAN {display: table-cell; white-space: nowrap; vertical-align: middle; }
H2 > SPAN:first-child + SPAN {padding: 0 .5em; width: 1px; }

/* Non-empty content and transparent color are needed for Opera 
   that otherwise does not display element as table.*/
H2 > SPAN:first-child:before,
H2 > SPAN + SPAN + SPAN:before {border-top: 1px solid #ccc; 
    color: transparent; content: "."; display: block; 
    height: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>

<h2><span></span><span>Services</span><span></span></h2>
```

Comment: You're blowin my mind! Really appreciate that, works perfectly! :)