# What is the best way to implement this structure?

Tags: html, css

We have a heading with two lines to the right and left of it.

The left line has to fill the remaining area to the left of the heading (minus a small margin), and the right line has to fill the remaining area to the right of the heading.

See below for an illustration of what I need.

[image: illustration]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468923/

Answer (score 1):

use a `<HR>` element to draw the line and place the DIV  with the text over it and give it the same background color as the page.

Comment: Thanks, it was my first decision, but it doesn`t work for me, becouse page background may be image.

Comment: Ok, so dont give it a background-color? It should inherit thebackground color from its parent, no?

Answer (score 0):

What about two inherited elements, where the parent one has a background with a line in it. The child element contains a white background and has a small padding. If you center the child element in the parent element, you should get the desired effect.

This for example should work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #header {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0;
                background: url(img/line.png) repeat-x;
            }

            #headertext{
                text-align: center;
            }

            #headertext h1 {
                display: inline;
                background-color: white;
                font-size: 150%;
                padding: 4px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headertext">
                <h1>Heading</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```