# trouble getting h2 element and left/right borders to align

Tags: html, css, padding, vertical-alignment

I have an h2 element that, ideally, should be aligned with it's left and right borders through it's vertical midpoint. I've tried `padding`, and `vertical-align:middle` but nothing seems to work. Ideas?

Thank you.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w8bmd/)

Comment: you mean like those horizontal bars should be in middle of that h2?

Comment: @HankyPanky aligned to the middle, yes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9468923

Comment: Similar problems, but def not a duplicate. Look at our avatars :)

Comment: Duplicate term does not mean that questions are asked by the same person. Duplicate means same/similar essence of issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've moved the `font-size` and added a `line-height` declaration to the `#title` element, as the `vertical-align` property is affected by these properties:

```
#save-the-date #title {
  padding-left: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 800px;
  font-size: 180%;
  line-height: 150%;
}
```

You only need to declare the h2 as an inline display style, unless you want the width fixed, in which case use inline-block and a width:

```
#save-the-date #title h2 {
  display: inline;
}
```

You can then have a single rule for both the spans, I removed the extra declarations for the background that weren't necessary:

```
#save-the-date #title span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #333333;
  width: 300px;
  height: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}​
```

The updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QjUw2/

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful answer; what you've said makes sense.
However, when I implement it on the site, I don't notice any changes.

simplyelegantweddingshowcase.com/

Any idea how to make it all work?

Comment: If you've put all the properties as required (the important ones are the display and vertical-align properties and which elements the font-size and line-height properties are declared for), I'd have to be able to examine the code to try and fix it, I don't have any ideas off the top of my head...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using **Line Height Property**

```
h2 { line-height: *font-size* }
```

Check CSS line-height..